# is it the mysql i'm having trouble with? fullcalendar

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, fullcalendar

i'm having trouble with fullcalendar. im not sure whether it is my php or mysql code. the calendar displays and i can add a new event but the event does not stick to the calendar. the event data does get inserted into the database but again it does not appear on the actual calendar itself.

here is the code i have so far:

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FullCalendar</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/fullcalendar.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.css' />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            /* global variables */
            var event_start = $('#event_start');
            var event_end = $('#event_end');
            var event_type = $('#event_type');
            var calendar = $('#calendar');
            var form = $('#dialog-form');
            var event_id = $('#event_id');
            var format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
            /* button to add events */
            $('#add_event_button').button().click(function(){
                formOpen('add');
            });
            /** cleaning function form */
            function emptyForm() {
                event_start.val("");
                event_end.val("");
                event_type.val("");
                event_id.val("");
            }
            /* opening form types*/
            function formOpen(mode) {
                if(mode == 'add') {
                    /* hide button Delete , Edit and display the Add*/
                    $('#add').show();
                    $('#edit').hide();
                    $("#delete").button("option", "disabled", true);
                }
                else if(mode == 'edit') {
                    /* hide the Add button , display the Edit and Delete*/
                    $('#edit').show();
                    $('#add').hide();
                    $("#delete").button("option", "disabled", false);
                }
                form.dialog('open');
            }
            /* date time picker */
            event_start.datetimepicker({hourGrid: 4, minuteGrid: 10, dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'});
            event_end.datetimepicker({hourGrid: 4, minuteGrid: 10, dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'});
            /* initialize full calendar */
            calendar.fullCalendar({
                firstDay: 1,
                height: 500,
                editable: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                monthNames: ['January','Feburary','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Jan.','Feb.','Маr','Apr.','May','Jun','Jul','Aug.','Sept.','Oct.','Nov.','Dec.'],
                dayNames: ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturdat"],
                dayNamesShort: ["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],
                buttonText: {
                    prev: "&nbsp;&#9668;&nbsp;",
                    next: "&nbsp;&#9658;&nbsp;",
                    prevYear: "&nbsp;&lt;&lt;&nbsp;",
                    nextYear: "&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&nbsp;",
                    today: "today",
                    month: "month",
                    week: "week",
                    day: "day"
                },
                /* time format output before the event name*/
                timeFormat: 'H:mm',
                /* click event handler for a particular day */
                dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                    var newDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, format);
                    event_start.val(newDate);
                    event_end.val(newDate);
                    formOpen('add');
                },
                /* handler for event click */
                eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    event_id.val(calEvent.id);
                    event_type.val(calEvent.title);
                    event_start.val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, format));
                    event_end.val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.end, format));
                    formOpen('edit');
                },
                /* record source */
                eventSources: [{
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        op: 'source'
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('Error connecting to the data source!');
                    }
                }]
            });
            /* form handler */
            form.dialog({ 
                autoOpen: false,
                buttons: [{
                    id: 'add',
                    text: 'add',
                    click: function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "ajax.php",
                            data: {
                                start: event_start.val(),
                                end: event_end.val(),
                                type: event_type.val(),
                                op: 'add'
                            },
                            success: function(id){
                                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                                                                        id: id,
                                                                        title: event_type.val(),
                                                                        start: event_start.val(),
                                                                        end: event_end.val(),
                                                                        allDay: false
                                                                    });
                                
                            }
                        });
   emptyForm();
                    }
                },
                {   id: 'edit',
                    text: 'edit',
                    click: function() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "ajax.php",
                            data: {
                                id: event_id.val(),
                                start: event_start.val(),
                                end: event_end.val(),
                                type: event_type.val(),
                                op: 'edit'
                            },
                            success: function(id){
                                calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                                
                            }
                        });
                        $(this).dialog('close');
   emptyForm();
                    }
                },
                {   id: 'cancel',
                    text: 'cancel',
                    click: function() { 
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        emptyForm();
                    }
                },
                {   id: 'delete',
                    text: 'delete',
                    click: function() { 
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "ajax.php",
                            data: {
                                id: event_id.val(),
                                op: 'delete'
                            },
                            success: function(id){
                                calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', id);
                            }
                        });
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        emptyForm();
                    },
                    disabled: true
                }]
            });
 });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="calendar"></div>
        <button id="add_event_button">Add Event</button>
        <div id="dialog-form" title="Событие">
            <p class="validateTips"></p>
            <form>
                <p><label for="event_type">type</label>
                <input type="text" id="event_type" name="event_type" value=""></p>
                <p><label for="event_start">start</label>
                <input type="text" name="event_start" id="event_start"/></p>
                <p><label for="event_end">end</label>
                <input type="text" name="event_end" id="event_end"/></p>
                <input type="hidden" name="event_id" id="event_id" value="">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```html
<?php 
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fullcalendar"); 

$start = $_POST['start']; 
$end = $_POST['end']; 
$type = $_POST['type']; 
$op = $_POST['op']; 
$id = $_POST['id']; 

switch ($op) { 
    case 'add': 
       $sql = 'INSERT INTO events ( 
            start,  
            end,  
            type)  
            VALUES  
            ("' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($start)) . '", 
            "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($end)) . '",  
            "' . $type . '")'; 
        if (mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql)) { 
            echo ((is_null($___mysqli_res = mysqli_insert_id($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"]))) ? false : $___mysqli_res); 
        } 
        break; 
    case 'edit': 
        $sql = 'UPDATE events SET  start = "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($start)) . '", 
                                    end      = "' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($end)) . '", 
                                    type  = "' . $type . '" 
                                    WHERE id = "' . $id . '"'; 
        if (mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql)) { 
            echo $id; 
        } 
        break; 
    case 'source': 
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM events'; 
        $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql); 
        $json = Array(); 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            $json[] = array( 
                'id' => $row['id'], 
                'title' => $row['type'], 
                'start' => $row['start'], 
                'end' => $row['end'], 
                'allDay' => false 
            ); 
        } 
        echo json_encode($json); 
        break; 
    case 'delete': 
        $sql = 'DELETE FROM events WHERE id = "' . $id . '"'; 
        if (mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], $sql)) { 
            echo $id; 
        } 
        break; 
}
```

i'd appreciate it if there could be any constructive input or help with this issue.

Comment: you need to localise the probelm

Comment: if it's getting added to db, see if ajax success is firing and if so check new object created in renderevent . Any errors thrown?

Comment: Paste the json generated with the events that no appear in the calendar

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks for the help. I had a look at the ajax like charlietfl said and I got a few errors thrown. They were mainly errors about the database connection but seeing as the events are getting inserted to the table it didn't seem correct. I double checked the syntax of the php and mysql and it turns out I was using a few mysql functions that have been depreciated in the newest version of php. It was recommended I changed it to match the PDO or mysqli structure to see if it would work and it did. Thanks for everybody's inputs i really appreciate it.